# What file format/database format does Picasa use?

Tags: database, picasa, file-extension

I am trying to figure out what file format the .db file and .pmp files are. I tried using db_dump (Berkeley DB) for the .db files, but it seems that they are not Berkeley DB, or of an older version. I have no idea what the .PMP files are.

```
Directory of C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google\Picasa2\db3
 6/09/2010  08:07 PM           303,748 imagedata_uid64.pmp
 1/18/2010  10:34 PM             4,885 imagedata_unification_lhlist.pmp
 6/09/2010  10:55 PM           155,752 imagedata_width.pmp
 6/09/2010  10:55 PM     1,286,346,614 previews_0.db
 6/10/2010  10:06 AM           467,168 previews_index.db
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: See: http://sbktech.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/picasa-pmp-format.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.PMP` is a format proprietory to Picasa, used to store informations about images. 
( [Reference](http://www.file-extensions.org/pmp-file-extension-google-picasa-file) )

( Note: Below referenced blog post is dated, not sure how relevant/correct it is to the current version of Picasa )

[More info:](http://forensicir.blogspot.com/2007/07/picasa.html)

> in the db2 directory there are a
>   number of files. The important files
>   for this are `albumdata_token.pmp`,
>   `albumdata_uid.pmp` and
>   `albumdata_name.pmp`
>
> Here are the contents of the files:
>
> `albumdata_name.pmp` -
>
> this is the name of the albums in
>   picasa. The first two
>   are defaults and are not included in
>   any of the other files.

```
Starred Photos

Screensaver 

root

modified_for_tags

sam3 

Sample Pictures 

Sammy
```

> `albumdata_uid.pmp` - This is where the
>   hashes are.

```
b131d7e17dfdff73eb0340b4e9d3d6f3

8e92a45a6abed421488a5774ec3f4a4c 

ca05c73419475ade037f8df528849c91

ec9771e026e3ce55c468354abcfce4ee

c332f1814ff6d4f21dbb41b41149544d
```

> `albumdata_token.pmp`
>
> Here's we see
>   the uid applied to create a token for
>   the albums. Note that "star" and
>   "screensaver" do not have uids.

```
]star

]screensaver

]album:b131d7e17dfdff73eb0340b4e9d3d6f3

]album:8e92a45a6abed421488a5774ec3f4a4c

]album:ca05c73419475ade037f8df528849c91

]album:ec9771e026e3ce55c468354abcfce4ee

]album:c332f1814ff6d4f21dbb41b41149544d
```

> Now, if we look at the
>   `lastalbumselected` value in the
>   registry, we can pair it up to the
>   hash since these files are all listed
>   in the same order. If you exclude `star`
>   and `screensaver` you can see that the
>   `lastalbumselected` for me was `sam3`.
>
> You can even go one step further if
>   you include albumdata_filename.pmp.
>   This file also matches up to the other
>   files, except I forgot to mention one
>   thing. "root" is literally the root of
>   the logical drive that picasa
>   searched(in this case C:), so it is
>   excluded from `albumdata_filename.pmp`.
>   This file contains the path to where
>   the images are stored.
>
> Other files to pay attention to:

```
bigthumbs.db 

thumbs2.db

thumbs.db

previews.db
```

> These all follow the good old
>   `thumbs.db` structure and contain
>   thumbnails of all of the images at
>   various resolutions, since picasa can
>   send files directly to photo
>   processing businesses.
>
> One other thing that is of pretty
>   vital importance in terms of proving
>   that someone created an album and that
>   the program didn't just index
>   something.
>
> In the `Picasa2Albums` directory you'll
>   see a file for each of the album(s)
>   created by the user under the folder
>   using the DBID as its name. Below are
>   the contents of the album I created
>   stored in a file named
>   {c332f1814ff6d4f21dbb41b41149544d.pal.

```
'picasa2album>

'dbid>0164eaeacdd4046f5c1e44522fe44527

'albumid>c332f1814ff6d4f21dbb41b41149544d

'property name="uid" type="string" value="c332f1814ff6d4f21dbb41b41149544d">

'property name="category" type="num" value="0"> 

'property name="date" type="real64" value="39272.630035"

'property name="token" type="string" value="]album:c332f1814ff6d4f21dbb41b41149544d"

'property name="name" type="string" value="Sammy"

'files>

'filename>[C]\sam3\sam1.jpg

'filename>[C]\sam3\sam3.jpg

'filename>[C]\sam3\sam2.jpg

'filename>[C]\sam3\DSCF1890.JPG

'/files> 

'/property>

'/picasa2album>
```

Answer (score 3):

I added [an answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467004/how-to-access-the-picasa-desktop-database/8482061#8482061) to a similar question about `.pmp` files, which also points to [some partial notes I wrote](http://sbktech.blogspot.com/2011/12/picasa-pmp-format.html) about the format of these files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read Picasa database by exportpicasa utility (http://sourceforge.net/projects/exportpicasa/). It's beta and feedbacks are welcome.

Comment: Looks like interesting project, but even though it's on Sourceforge there's no code and no documentation, just a bare .exe with a one sentence overview. I don't run such things outside a sandbox with realtime process and file monitoring. I don't have one available right now and there's not enough incentive to make one. If you want this project to get used I suggest documentation, at the very least.